# Read line from text file Java?

Tags: java, file

So I'm new to Java, and everything I'm trying, isn't working. There are so many different ways to read from a file, so I'm wondering the easiest way. Basically, it's a Mad Libs application. One method. I have been trying to run this successfully, and I get an error on the `file.close()` function. If I take it away, I get `FileNotFoundException errors`. So I'm kind of lost. What should I change?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] nouns = new String[4];
    String[] verbs = new String[6];
    String[] adjectives = new String[7];
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please input 4 nouns, press \"Enter\" after each input.");
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        nouns[i] = s.next();
    }
    System.out.println("Please input 6 verbs, press \"Enter\" after each input.");
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
        verbs[i] = s.next();
    }
    System.out.println("Please input 7 adjectives, press \"Enter\" after each input.");
    for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
        adjectives[i] = s.next();
    }
    File file = null;
    FileReader fr = null;
    LineNumberReader lnr = null;

    try {
        file = new File("H:\\10GraceK\\AP Computer Science\\Classwork\\src\\madlib.txt");
        fr = new FileReader(file);           
        lnr = new LineNumberReader(fr);
        String line = "";           
        while ((line = lnr.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);               
        }
    } finally {
        if (fr != null) {
            fr.close();
        }
        if (lnr != null) {
            lnr.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Ok, I fixed the exception. Now the text in the file reads verbs[0], and stuff like that, but it actually outputs the verbs[0], not the word in the array. How do I append a string in the array to the string that was read?

Comment: Can you post the full exception please?

Comment: The Scanner class has classes that can read from a file line by line as well as from the command line. It might be worth checking out, it's a newer implementation (Java 1.4 I think) so it could be smoother.

Comment: Exception is fixed, new problem below my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method `close` is undefined for `File`. Use `FileReader.close` instead. Replace

```
file.close();
```

with

```
fr.close();
```

In fact closing the `LineNumberReader` will suffice as this will close the underlying `FileReader`. You can place the `close` in a `finally` block. See this [example](http://www.javadb.com/using-the-linenumberreader-class)

Comment: I posted the exception above, I still get FileNotFound. But, it at least compiles. I can run through the nouns verbs and adjectives, then it throws the exception.

Answer (score 2):

As always I have to recommend [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) when it comes to reading files and streams.

Try using for example:

```
IOUtils.readLines
```

The error in your code is as @Reimeus mentioned the missing method.

Comment: Who would want to used buffered readers and such when they could just use this?

Answer (score 0):

The Scanner API improved and turn it more easy:

```
try {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("text.txt"));
    sc.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    String ln = sc.next();

} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(this.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```